# Frontend (React) doesn't send requests to backend (Spring Boot) on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku

I deployed my frontend (ReactJS) and my backend(Spring Boot) as two different apps (with different addresses) to Heroku. Frontend link: https://front-for-app.herokuapp.com. Backend link: https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com. On React in file **setupProxy.js** wrote an address of backend:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
 
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

In browser console I have seen such an error:
[image]

I tryed to write even proxy in **package.json**:

```
"proxy": "https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com",
```

Tell me please - how can I redirect requests from the frontend (on Heroku) to backend?
After making configuration in **setupProxy.js** I can sent request from the frontend (on my local machine) to the backend on Heroku.

UPD: Case #1 - client from localhost (localhost:3000) send request to the backend on localhost (localhost:9090).
*setupProxy.js* (without createProxyMiddleware):

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:9090',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

And here is screen with the result:
[image]

Case #2: Then I change target in *setupProxy.js* to Heroku backend address:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

And here is the result of the same request:
[image]

Here is the part of the controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://front-for-app.herokuapp.com")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/get/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List getFileList() {
        return fireService.getAll();
    }
```

And here is the method to get all files from the DB:

```
@Transactional
public List getAll() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List list = session.createQuery("SELECT FE.fileName FROM FileEntity AS FE ")
            .list();
    return list;
}
```

UPD2: Here is the screenshot of the answer that backend returns to me if I send request manually:
[image]

Comment: 404 means this path doesn't exist. Are you sure it works on `localhost`? Post some backend code...

Comment: @k-wasilewski, thank you for your respond. I posted some results of my requests and a part of backend. Tell me please if I can clarify my case more.

Comment: Can you see if the backend is being called? Maybe the translation of the url is wrong in the proxy

Comment: @Anderson Danilo, yes I can see when backend returns me answer. I just have added a screenshot of that answer. What do you mean "the translation of the url"?
I checked all urls many times. And unfortunately they are all correct. Thank you!

Comment: @Anderson Danilo, 
UPD: one thing confuses me. When frontend send its request it looks like "https://front-for-app.herokuapp.com/api/get/all" or *localhost:3000/api/get/all". When I send request to backend manually I send "https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com/api/get/all" or "localhost:9090/api/get/all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out. The `setupProxy.js` file is only for the development. To make production code we have to create `static.json` file in the root of the project.
In my case the code of this file is:

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    },
    "proxies": {
        "/api/": {
            "origin": "https://back-for-app.herokuapp.com/api"
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the `/api"` in the end of the address - this part is very important. Nothing works without this `/api"`